# If condition not working properly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Actually I'm facing logical problem in this code

*Issue* : While I'm putting the right emp_id and password,the if portion is running properly,but within this if condition whenever I'm trying to running this page(Run as->Run on Server-Tomcat server)....it's going to the else condition-which makes me unable run the jsp page whithin the if clause.

```
              else {
              resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

                          }
```

*I want to run the jsp page aswell when it satisfy the if clause.*

Here is my code:

```
     try {
          String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/app";
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"****","******");
          stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from ofc where emp_id=? and password=?");
          stmt.setString(1, employee);
          stmt.setString(2, password);

          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

          if(rs.next()) {  //I want to print this jsp page for this If condition
              System.out.println("2> Employee Id : "+employee+" && Password : "+password);
              System.out.println("3> This employee "+employee+" exsists in the database and will be there");      

              resp.setContentType("text/html");
              PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
              out.print("<html><body>");       // It's my JSP page,& start from here
              out.print("<head>");
              out.print("<title>Policy Page</title>");
              out.print("</head>");
              List<String> devices = Store.getDevices();
              if (devices.isEmpty())
              {
                out.print("<h2>No  One is there!</h2>");
              } 
              else
              {    
               out.print("<h2>" + devices.size() + " device(s) are there!</h2>");
               out.print("<form name='form' method='POST' action='sendAll'>");
               out.print("<input type='text' name='policy'>");
               resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
               out.print("<input type='submit' value='Apply Policy'>");
               out.print("</form>");
//             getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);

              }
              out.print("</body></html>");       //Completes here
              resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

          }


          else {
              resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

                          }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Where I'm going wrong....in this coding context ...//

Comment: `but within this if condition whenever I'm trying to running this page....it's going to the else condition` -- How can it go to an else condition once it is inside your if?? Can you please explain better?? Which `else` are you talking about??

Comment: yes...whenever I run this code in Tomcat Server,it's going to the else-part.And that's quiet relevant as far as my code concern.

Comment: @RohitJain It should be the `else` from the first `if`.

Comment: @user1645434 you should provide your `doPost` method and the JSP that you use to call your servlet.

Comment: Didn't get the problem. What does happen under which condition? Do you want the if(rs.next())-Code to run more than once?

Comment: @user1645434 Have you check the result set has the values in it?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza.. If you mean inner else, then that is actually executing a JSP?? What JSP code is OP pointing to??

Comment: @RohitJain I assume the problem is that OP has problem getting the user and password from the JSP form, so his/her code is always going to the other scenario. That's why I'm asking the JSP code and the full `doPost` servlet code.

Comment: I'm trying to run the jsp is written under the 1st If condition.I'm using google gcm in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug your code, does the debugger go into the IF statement - actually enter within the inner brackets of the IF statement, or does it merely evaluate the IF statement, (evaluate at it to "IF(False)") and then move on to the else statement?

Maybe your mySQL query doesn't return any results? Try using the HasRows property.

```
if (rs.HasRows) 
{ 
    while (rs.Read()) 
    { 
        // do stuff
    } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
       // notify user that query returned no results
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps by which you can identify and solve this issue.

1. Check username, password exists in the table
2. Try adding `employee.trim()` and `password.trim()` if there are any extra spaces. You will get NullPointerException if values of `employee` or `password` are null. So this is the cause. then check for null and then again try with `trim()`
3. Print result before the query so you will come to know what is that you are doing wrong.
4. If you are using Request Parameters then you need to pass it in URL `?employeeid=someId&password=somepass`

Comment: I only accord with step 3. Step 2 could fail if `employee` or `password` have `null` value.

Comment: Then he will come to know the reason :)

Comment: I'm able to authenticate properly in terms of employee and password.but when running it like Run as->Run on Server...this java file...then then it stisfy the else condition.

Comment: How are you passing employee and password in that case? Can you add a print statement before executing the query?

Comment: String employee=req.getParameter("employeeid");
String password=req.getParameter("password");

Comment: @user1645434 how are you setting those variables in your request parameter map when you run the Java class? (Hint: you can't, you should use a URL call).

Comment: Yes in that case if it not present in request and you are directly launching this page then it will always give you error. You will have to check first whether they are present in request or not. So you will need to add a print for that and then I am sure it will print null in your case.

Comment: suppose,within the 1st If condition,I write jsp code->then if condition satisfied->how to run that jsp page ...?

Comment: You need to pass request parameters in the URL Call `?employeeid=someId&password=somepass`

Comment: Supposing you map your servlet as `/MyServlet`, then you have to write this in your URL bar: `http://<your_ip>:8080/YourWebAppName/MyServlet?employeeid=someId&password=somepass` to test your class.

Answer (score 0):

Your Resultset is empty, thats why your getting into the else statement. Try to execute the SQL directly on the database, do you get any records?

Im not sure this solves your problem (it depends if your debugging on checking the code only based on the output) but your HTML structur is wrong: it sould be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>

   </HEAD>
   <BODY>

   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

your mixing the HEAD part into the BODY.

Comment: Notice your having a html structure mistake, the head part doesnt belong inthe body part but before ist, see this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html